# $(this) is null inside .click(function(){...}), why?

Tags: jquery, this

I've got this jquery code, that allows me to click on a link to fetch its parent and change some value in another place:

```
$("a.menu_filter_select").click(function(){
  var parent_filter = $(this).parent("tr");
  // Update value
  parent_filter.find(".filter_value").html($(this).html());
});
```

The problem is that it gets a null value on *$(this)*, that's an unexpected behavior, I don't understand why it doesn't work, any idea?

Here is the console debug with a breakpoint inside the method:

```
$(this)
> null
this
> <a class=​"menu_filter_select" href=​"http:​/​/​localhost:​3000/​#" rel=​"1">​test</a>​
```

Comment: can you please post the html Code for this section ? A quick fix would be to use .parents("tr:eq(0)")

Comment: .parents() methods can't be called, because $(this) is null

Comment: yes, i think there is an html mistake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's because your function receives an event as an argument, and you need event.target.

```
$('a.menu_filter_select').click(function(evt) {
    var parent_filter = $(evt.target).closest('tr');
```

I also recommend using `closest` instead of `parent`, since your code will work even if someone puts `<b>`, `<i>` or `<span>` around the anchor. I also use `find` instead of `child`.

Edit: in fact, `this` in FireFox refers to the anchor object, but I can't for sure if it's implemented the same way in other browsers. **BUT** event.target can refer to the child object if, say the document is like this:

```
<a><b>some text</b> other text</a>
```

then this event handler can output different elements:

```
$(a).click(function(event) { console.log(this, event.target); });
```

Try running this code in FireBug, see how it works.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason I can think of for that to happen, is that the identifier `$` has been redefined.

You can check if `$ == jQuery` in the function. If it's not, then you probably have included another script that uses the `$` identifier too.

There is a compatibility mode for jQuery to be used if there is another library that also uses that identifier, where it returns the value of the `$` identifier to it's original value, and you use the `jQuery` identifier instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check $ == jQuery next time I've got a problem like this one.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally the binding between $ and jQuery can fail, try replacing the $ with jQuery.

Also try using $.log rather than a breakpoint to ensure that the scope of the this is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I always use $ when using jquery, but I have seen this happen where I included a plugin which used jquery rather than $. For some reason it doesn't like using both, but just changing the jquery to $ in the plugin code sorted it out for me.